# Переменная, считающая текущее время с момента инициализации

Tags: java, android, таймер

Нужно инициализировать переменную delta_t, которая с момента запуска приложения или активити будет считать время. Нужно для ПИД-регулятора. Пробовал делать через секундомер и таймеры, но как-то неудобно и громоздко. Я думаю, что есть какие-то решения с помощью `SystemClock`. Могу я просто определить `long delta_t=какая-то функция`, чтобы вернуть время с момента инициализации? Смотрю здесь [на developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html), но не уверен, что я могу использовать и насколько это будет правильно. Видел варианты реализации через цикл с усыплением потока на секунду, но что-то не очень нравится данный подход. Подскажите, какой оптимальный и правильный способ я мог бы использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сохраняете время вызова метода `onCreate(...)`;
2. При необходимости, вызываете метод, который будет вычислять разницу между значением, сохраненным в пункте 1 и текущим временем.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private long mInitTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private long getDeltaT() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - mInitTime;
    }
}
```

Если же нужно непосредственное изменение переменной с некоторой периодичностью, то можете запустить таймер и в нем обновлять время.

Comment: спасибо, это то, что нужно